# Laptop goes into sleep mode when already shutting down

Tags: laptop, windows-10, sleep, shutdown

I have a Dell E6530 laptop with Windows 10. When I shut down Windows and then close the laptop a few seconds later, it begins to shut down but still into sleep mode. When I press the power button later expecting the computer to start, it wakes up to the "Shutting Down" message. How can I tell the computer to not go into sleep mode when it already started shutting down?

Comment: Same problem, affects all windows installations, what's the fix? I'm BAFFLED